# Catching all routes in Aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

How can I catch absolutely all the paths from the received request? I am using the following code, however it does not work.

```
routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get(path='/{key}')
async def _(request):
    print(request)
    await self.processing_request(request=request, post=False)

@routes.post(path='/{key}')
async def _(request):
    await self.processing_request(request=request, post=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The default regex for variable paths is `[^{}/]+`, i.e. it will not match forward slashes. You can specify a custom regex in the path string using `{variablename:regex}` syntax:

```
@routes.get(path="/{key:.+}")
async def _(request):
    ...
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#variable-resources):

> A variable part is specified in the form {identifier}, where the
> identifier can be used later in a request handler to access the
> matched value for that part. This is done by looking up the identifier
> in the Request.match_info mapping ...
>
> By default, each part matches the regular expression [^{}/]+.
>
> You can also specify a custom regex in the form {identifier:regex}:

(disclaimer: I have not tested)